# How to set custom laravel resource controller request url

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I want to change the default request url! ex.

GET `/photos/{photo}/edit change` to `/photos/{photo}/update`
GET `/photos/create` change to `/photos/createOnePhoto`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change default `resource()` routes. You can tell Laravel to not build some of them by using `->except(['update', 'create'])`.

Add all custom routes manually:

```
Route::get('photos/createOnePhoto', ['as' => 'photo.createOne', 'uses' => 'PhotoController@createOnePhoto'])
```

Comment: Thx, buddy, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9 you can use [Localizing Resource URIs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-localizing-resource-uris) on your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`.

```php
public function boot()
{
    Route::resourceVerbs([
        'create' => 'crear',
        'edit' => 'editar',
    ]);
 
    // ...
}
```